# Connect Sequelize/Node to XAMPP Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, xampp, sequelize.js

I've a working script to connect and work with Sequelize on Node.js
 But now i'm trying to connect this to my MySQL database on XAMPP

> MySQL Port on XAMPP: 3306

When i run node.js after i have configured the app.listen and the config of sequealize i get the following error

> ERROR: listen EADDRINUSE :::3306

I've looked for but i didn't find much information about that, i don't know what i'm doing bad.
Thanks you for every answer!

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const { sequelize } = require('./models')
const config = require('./config/config')

const app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

require('./routes')(app)

sequelize.sync()
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(config.db.options.port || 3306) // 8081 original
    console.log(`Server iniciado en puerto: ${config.db.options.port}`)
  })
```

config.js

```
module.exports = {
  db: {
    database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'intraenvios',
    user: process.env.DB_USER || 'root',
    password: process.env.DB_PASS || '',
    options: {
      dialect: process.env.DIALECT || 'mysql', // sqlite original
      host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
      storage: './intraenvios.sqlite',
      port: process.env.PORT || 3306 // 8081 original
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Check your mysql server running of which port @Natarr

Comment: @PrashantGupta I think it's running on 3306. Post updated, could you see the img and tell me if i'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Your code is fine.Open `CMD `and try to login using this command  `mysql -u root -p` then enter password @Natarr

Comment: I'm on windows and i've only installed MySQL through XAMPP. @PrashantGupta

Comment: Please Insure your mysql is running of port 3306. This error means your port is bind to other service or mysql is not running of other port @Natarr. There is option in xampp also to login mysql and you can open xampp ulr using this ` http://localhost/phpmyadmin` there you can check mysql running or not .

Comment: `dialect: process.env.DIALECT || 'sqlite', // sqlite original` just change `sqlite` to` mysql` then please let me know @Natarr

Comment: Oh yes, sorry i hadn't understood you. I'm able to access through the URL, it works great.
 Even before send the error on console, sequelize has created the table correctly, but then it send the error and doesn't work anymore

Comment: @PrashantGupta Yes, i've realized about the dialect after posting, i changed that but still is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For to connect by xampp simply, i made this:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'root', '', {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  dialect : 'mysql',
  operatorsAliases: false
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(function(){
      console.log("sucess");
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log("error: "+error);
});
```

Obs: operatorsAliases: false - To fix deprecated message of sequelize

Good Fun :)